# Count decade occurrences

Tags: python, perl, unix, awk, grep

infile:

```
1   3
2   3
3   3
4   3
8   3
9   3
12  3
14  3
18  3
19  3
20  3
25  3
26  3
27  3
28  3
30  3
31  3
32  3
36  3
38  3
101 3
109 3
```

Once I knew a one liner to count the decade occurrences. E.g. 5 thirties... 
I hope you do now. A python script would be awesome.

Desired output:

```
0    6
1    4
2    5
3    4
10    2
```

Comment: Count the decades (I think thats correct english)

Comment: Not a problem with your english my friend. Just couldnt understand your desired output from `E.g. 5 thirties` .. rest of the lines doesn't really help (if you know what I mean) ;) If you can give a desired output using your infile that would help.

Comment: But there are only 3 thirties!

Comment: @katrielalex - I think the second number is irrelevant.  There are 5 lines where the first number is in thirties so I am assuming it is just the first number he cares about.

Comment: @AxelWilhelmEinarsson Thanks for putting up your desired output. Have added my answer in the mix. Hope that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `awk` one-liner for you -

```
awk '{x=$1/10; a[int(x)]++} END{for(i in a) print i,a[i] | "sort -n"}' INPUT_FILE
```

Test:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file
1   3
2   3
3   3
4   3
8   3
9   3
12  3
14  3
18  3
19  3
20  3
25  3
26  3
27  3
28  3
30  3
31  3
32  3
36  3
38  3
101 3
109 3

[jaypal:~/Temp] awk '{x=$1/10; a[int(x)]++} END{for(i in a) print i,a[i] | "sort -n"}' file
0 6
1 4
2 5
3 5
10 2
```

Comment: You can further shorten it by including the `sort` inside of `awk`. I should have done it earlier. But here it is - `awk '{x=$1/10; a[int(x)]++} END{for (i in a) print i,a[i] | "sort -n"}' INPUT_FILE`

Answer (score 5):

With Perl, use a hash:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my %decs;
while (<DATA>) {
    my ($n) = /([0-9]+)/;
    my $x = int($n / 10);
    $decs{$x}++;
}
print "$_ $decs{$_}\n" for sort { $a <=> $b } keys %decs;

__DATA__
1   3
2   3
3   3
4   3
8   3
9   3
12  3
14  3
18  3
19  3
20  3
25  3
26  3
27  3
28  3
30  3
31  3
32  3
36  3
38  3
101 3
109 3
```

Output:

```
0 6
1 4
2 5
3 5
10 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite grok what you're attempting to do here, but I think you're looking for something as simple as

```
from collections import defaultdict
decades = defaultdict(int)
for line in open('infile.txt', 'r'):
    decades[int(line.split()[0]) / 10] += 1
for decade, count in decades:
    print "%s people in their %s0s" % (count, decade * 10)
```

Comment: I think this version will sum the values from second column for distinct values from the first column, so not exactly what OP asked for...

Comment: He didn't have examples when I posted my answer, so I had to guess at what he wanted. I'll edit my answer to respond to the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correclty:

```
perl -ne '{use integer; $i{$_/=10}++} END{ map { print $_*10," : $i{$_}\n" } sort keys %i }'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this python module will do what you need:

```
import sys
import math
from collections import OrderedDict 

def count_decades( infile ):
    decade_counts = OrderedDict()
    for line in infile:
        number = int( line.split( ' ' )[ 0 ] )
        decade_index = int( math.floor( number / 10 ) )
        decade_counts[ decade_index ] = decade_counts.get( decade_index, 0 ) + 1
    return decade_counts

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    with open( sys.argv[ 1 ], 'r' ) as infile:
        decade_counts = count_decades( infile )        
        for key, count in decade_counts.items():
            print( "{} - {} occurs {} times".format( 
                key * 10 , key * 10 + 9, count ) )
```

When invoked like this:

```
python occur.py decades.txt
```

The result is:

```
0 - 9 occurs 6 times
10 - 19 occurs 4 times
20 - 29 occurs 5 times
30 - 39 occurs 5 times
100 - 109 occurs 2 times
```

You may need different output, but it should be easy to customize...

UPDATE:

For OPs desired output change:

```
print( "{} - {} occurs {} times".format( 
                key * 10 , key * 10 + 9, count ) )
```

to

```
print( "{} {}".format( 
                key , count ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.7:

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(int(line.split()[0]) // 10 for line in open("infile"))
for k, v in sorted(c.iteritems()):
    print k, v
```

Comment: looks good but... for k, v in sorted(c):
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: @AxelWilhelmEinarsson: Sorry, fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Other `perl` solution:

```
perl -ane '
  $h{ int( $F[0] / 10 ) }++;
  END {
    for $num ( sort { $a <=> $b } keys %h ) {
      printf qq[%d\t%d\n], $num, $h{ $num }
    }
  }
' file
```

Result:

```
0       6
1       4
2       5
3       5
10      2
```

Comment: Using a hash for a tight group of numbers is a waste, IMO. It works just as well to store it in `$h[ int( $F[0] / 10 ) ]` as well.

Answer (score 0):

One line Python itertools solution (should work for Python >= 2.4):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> sorted((key, len(list(group))) for key, group in groupby(
...        int(line.split()[0]) // 10 for line in open('infile')))
[(0, 6), (1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 5), (10, 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short one in Perl :)

```
perl -nE 'END{say"$_\t$h{$_}"for sort{$a<=>$b}keys%h}++$h{$_/5>>1}' input.txt
```

```
0       6
1       4
2       5
3       5
10      2
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed 's/\S\s*\S*$//;s/^$/0/' file | uniq -c | sed 's/\s*\(\S*\)\s\(\S*\)/\2\t\1/'
0       6
1       4
2       5
3       5
10      2
```

It looks as if your data is sorted, if not insert a `sort -n` like so:

```
sed 's/\S\s*\S*$//;s/^$/0/' file | sort -n | uniq -c | sed 's/\s*\(\S*\)\s\(\S*\)/\2\t\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
perl -ne '$h{$.=$_/10}++}{print"$_ $h{$_}\n"for sort{$a-$b}keys%h' infile.txt
```

Output:

```
0       6
1       4
2       5
3       5
10      2
```

Can be shortened further with `-E` and `say` if available.